CRASH: Swift UIKit Dictionary _NativeSet.startIndex.getter
This crash is happening in production and is related to UICollectionView.CellRegistration or dequeueConfiguredReusableCell or UIViewController being deallocated.
Here is the report:
Crashlytics - Stack Trace
Application: <appName>
Platform: Apple
Version: 2.2.14 (30)
Issue ID: 6f9f49c30dcc78da2676dcf048076083
Session: 6f812a773f604e83a4c8d9af26a2a63e_DNE_0_v2
Date: Mon, Sep 09, 2024, 19:25:48 GMT+0800 (Hong Kong Standard Time)



Index
Module
Memory Address
Function/Method
Offset




0
<appName>
0x207910
specialized _NativeSet.startIndex.getter
+4379932944


1
<appName>
0x1f85f8
closure #1 in DestinationVC.configureDataSource()
+223 (DestinationVC.swift:223)


2
UIKitCore
0x5f08f0
__swift_memcpy64_8
+33316


3
UIKitCore
0x5f093c
__swift_memcpy64_8
+33392


4
UIKitCore
0x5f06a0
__swift_memcpy64_8
+32724


5
UIKitCore
0x2a10e0
-[UICollectionView dequeueConfiguredReusableCellWithRegistration:forIndexPath:item:]
+604


6
UIKitCore
0x5f0cd4
__swift_memcpy64_8
+34312


7
<appName>
0x20377c
partial apply for closure #4 in DestinationVC.configureDataSource()
+234 (DestinationVC.swift:234)


8
<appName>
0x2037cc
partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed
+4379916236 (:4379916236)


9
UIKitCore
0xc0f0c
-[_UICollectionLayoutFramesQueryResultElementIndexKey isEqual:]
+328


10
UIKitCore
0xc0e20
-[_UICollectionLayoutFramesQueryResultElementIndexKey isEqual:]
+92


11
UIKitCore
0x2a4e9c
-[_UIDiffableDataSourceSectionController configureCell:forItem:]
+568


12
UIKitCore
0x2a4920
-[__UIDiffableDataSource collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]
+144


13
UIKitCore
0x2a0be4
+[UIColor redColor]
+152


14
UIKitCore
0x2a4fd0
-[_UIDiffableDataSourceSectionController configureCell:forItem:]
+876


15
UIKitCore
0x2a1ce8
-[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:]
+1000


16
UIKitCore
0x2a1714
-[UICollectionView _createVisibleViewsForSingleCategoryAttributes:limitCreation:fadeForBoundsChange:]
+1116


17
UIKitCore
0x3d950c
-[UICollectionView _createVisibleViewsForAttributes:fadeForBoundsChange:notifyLayoutForVisibleCellsPass:]
+300


18
UIKitCore
0x1ca064
-[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]
+3060


19
UIKitCore
0x335af8
-[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
+304


20
UIKitCore
0x10918
-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
+1528


21
QuartzCore
0x7f26c
CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
+504


22
QuartzCore
0x7edf0
CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
+148


23
QuartzCore
0xd9fd8
CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
+464


24
QuartzCore
0x4eee0
CA::Transaction::commit()
+648


25
QuartzCore
0x98c34
CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool)
+88


26
UIKitCore
0xb9ee8
_UIApplicationFlushCATransaction
+52


27
UIKitCore
0xb7660
_UIUpdateSequenceRun
+84


28
UIKitCore
0xb72a4
schedulerStepScheduledMainSection
+172


29
UIKitCore
0xb8148
runloopSourceCallback
+92


30
CoreFoundation
0x56834
CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION
+28


31
CoreFoundation
0x567c8
__CFRunLoopDoSource0
+176


32
CoreFoundation
0x54298
__CFRunLoopDoSources0
+244


33
CoreFoundation
0x53484
__CFRunLoopRun
+828


34
CoreFoundation
0x52cd8
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
+608


35
GraphicsServices
0x11a8
GSEventRunModal
+164


36
UIKitCore
0x40aae8
-[UIApplication _run]
+888


37
UIKitCore
0x4bed98
UIApplicationMain
+340


38
UIKitCore
0x638504
keypath_get_selector_hoverStyle
+11024


39
<appName>
0x1ca0dc
main
+4379680988 (AppDelegate.swift:4379680988)


40
???
0x1b15c7154
(Missing)




Here is the method in question along with where it is called right back to viewDidLoad:
(Please forgive my terrible code)
private func configureDataSource() {
    let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<DestinationViewCell, AnimalResult.ID> { [weak self] (cell, indexPath, animalID) in
        guard let self,
              let thisDestination,
              let i = self.destVCAnimals.firstIndex (where: { animalResult in
                  animalResult.id == animalID }) else { return }
        let animal = self.destVCAnimals[i]
        cell.configureCell(destination: thisDestination, animal: animal)
    }
    let sectionHeaderRegistration = UICollectionView.SupplementaryRegistration<SectionHeaderView>(elementKind: SectionHeaderView.ident) { (sectionHeaderView, kind, indexPath) in }
    let layoutHeaderRegistration = UICollectionView.SupplementaryRegistration<LayoutHeaderView>(elementKind: LayoutHeaderView.ident) { (layoutHeaderView, kind, indexPath) in }
    dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource(collectionView: collectionView) {
        collectionView, indexPath, animalID -> DestinationViewCell in
        return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: animalID)
    }
    dataSource.supplementaryViewProvider = { [weak self] (collectionView: UICollectionView, kind: String, indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView? in
        if kind == "header-view" {
            // Section Header
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableSupplementary(
                using: sectionHeaderRegistration,
                for: indexPath)
            guard let self else { return headerView }
            let sectionIdentifiers = dataSource.snapshot().sectionIdentifiers
            let sectionIconicID = sectionIdentifiers[indexPath.section]
            guard let animalIDs = iconicTaxons[sectionIconicID] else { return headerView }
            if let thisDestination,
               let viewModel {
                headerView.configure(viewModel, iconicTaxon: (id: sectionIconicID, animals: animalIDs), destination: thisDestination)
                if indexPath.section == 0,
                   viewModel.userIsInThisDestination(),
                   thisDestination.headerBlurbIsSet() {
                    addTouchView(headerView, indexPath)
                }
            }
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSectionHeaderTapGesture(_:)))
            headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            return headerView
        } else {
            // Layout Header
            let layoutHeaderView = collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableSupplementary(
                using: layoutHeaderRegistration,
                for: indexPath)
            guard let self else { return layoutHeaderView }
            if let thisDestination {
                layoutHeaderView.configure(destination: thisDestination)
            }
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            return layoutHeaderView
        }
    }
    self.configureSnapshot()
}


private func setupUI() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        guard let self else { return }
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        let titleLabelText = thisDestination.destinationName ?? thisDestination.myCommunity?.displayName
        titleLabel.text = titleLabelText
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 3
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .natural
        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
        self.title = titleLabel.text
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = titleLabel.text
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.style = .browser

        titleLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.navigationItem.titleView?.layoutIfNeeded()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleNavBarTapGesture(_:)))
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
        let styleTrait: UITrait = UITraitUserInterfaceStyle.self
        print("styleTrait: \(styleTrait)")
        self.registerForTraitChanges([styleTrait]) { (self: Self, previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection) in
            self.configureDataSource()
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    self.createEmptyView()
    self.configureCollectionView()
    self.applyConstraints()
    self.setupUI()
    self.configureDataSource()
    self.watch()
    
}


I've done a weird thing: I'm calling configureDataSource() from viewDidLoad() and from setupUI().  I think it's possibly the cause of the problem although I'm not sure.
I think it's because there is not a lot of documentation on registerForTraitChanges().
